# Scala immutable SortedSet are not "stable" on deletion

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I've to deal with an immutable object in scala 2.7.5, and one of its member is an [immutable Sortedset](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/api/scala/collection/immutable/SortedSet.html).
I've no problem with addition, to synthetise, it gives:

```
class MyClass[A](s:SortedSet[A]) {
  ...
  def  + (elem:A):MyClass[A] {
    new MyClass(s + elem)
  }
}
```

And it works, since + operator is overload in trait sortedSet to return a SortedSet.

Unfortunately removing an element fails since - methos is not overloaded:

```
class MyClass[A](s:SortedSet[A]) {
  ...
  def  - (elem:A):MyClass[A] {
    new MyClass(s - elem) // Compiler error: (s - elem) is a Set[A]
  }
}
```

Does anyone knows how I can obtain a sorted set when i suppress an element knowing that:
- I don't want to use a more specific kind of set like TreeSet.
- I can't use a less specific trait as Set[A] instead of my SortedSet.

Comment: How I've checked the SortedMap API and... it does it properly ("-" returns a SortedMap). There must be an explanation, bonus question?

Comment: Scala 2.7.x's collection library is ad-hoc. It grew with time and use, until it got to the way it is. Removing this kind of inconsistency is one goal behind Scala 2.8's new collection library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can wait until 2.8, it looks like this will work properly.

From [SortedSetLike.scala](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/trunk/src/library/scala/collection/SortedSetLike.scala) (the super-trait of the immutable `SortedSet` trait)

```
trait SortedSetLike[A, +This <: SortedSet[A] with SortedSetLike[A, This]] extends Sorted[A, This] with SetLike[A, This]
```

This makes the `This` type a `SortedSet`.  Then in [SetLike.scala](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/trunk/src/library/scala/collection/SetLike.scala), the `-` operator's signature is

```
def - (elem: A): This
```

So will correctly return a `SortedSet` when used on a `SortedSet`.

Comment: Yes, things are better in 2.8. But unfortunately, I need a workaround for the 2.7.5.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: Figured that was probably the case, but thought it might be useful anyway

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what one may think, `-` will not guarantee a `SortedSet` result. Small sets are optimized through different classes. Since Set's `-` is abstract, you don't know how it might be implemented, and a `SortedSet` is free to implement it in a way which returns a non-sorted set.

The following is inefficient, but it works. You can use it, live with `asInstanceOf`, or wait for 2.8. :-)

```
class MyClass[A](s: SortedSet[A]) {
  def -(elem: A)(implicit view: A => Ordered[A]): MyClass[A] = {
    new MyClass(TreeSet(s.toList - elem: _*))
  }
}
```

Comment: Why did you put the implicit on the method instead of the class? If I understand well, the implicit parameter can change from a call to another and it seems awkward, did I miss something?
And yes: risk an cast error, wait or use an inefficient method seems to be the only alternatives. I guess I've to live with it.

Comment: No particular reason for the implicit on the method. I was just trying to preserve `MyClass` declaration as you wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is cast it.  "-" returns a Set but it is also a SortedSet.  It may not be pretty but it works:

```
class MyClass[A](s:SortedSet[A]) {
    def  +(elem:A): MyClass[A] = {
      new MyClass(s + elem)
    }

    def  -(elem:A): MyClass[A] = {
      new MyClass((s - elem).asInstanceOf[SortedSet[A]])
    }

    override def toString = "sorted set = " + s
  }

  val a = new MyClass(new TreeSet[Int])
  println(a) // prints "sorted set = Set()"
  val b = a + 1
  println(b) // prints "sorted set = Set(1)"
  val c = a - 1
  println(c) // prints "sorted set = Set()"
```

Comment: I 'm doing it, as most of the SortedSet must return a SortedSet after a "-". But I don't like the ClassCastException risk that comes with that solution.